# Why is the resource stream always null?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource

Hopefully something simple but have tried and tried and keep failing.
I am attempting to create a `Stream` object in a C# application that will copy a CSS file to a specific location.
The CSS file is embedded in my resources.
Regardles of what I have tried the stream object is always null.

Can somebody please point in the right direction by looking at the below?

Thanks :) burrows111

```
Assembly Assemb = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream stream = Assemb.GetManifestResourceStream(ThisNameSpace.Properties.Resources.ClockingsMapStyle); // NULL!!!!
FileStream fs = new FileStream("to store in this location", FileMode.Create);
StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(stream);
StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
Writer.Write(Reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: From MSDN `This method returns a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if a private resource in another assembly is accessed and the caller does not have ReflectionPermission with the ReflectionPermissionFlag.TypeInformation flag.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
StreamReader reader;
StreamWriter writer;
Stream stream;
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.Stylesheet1.css"))
using (reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (writer = new StreamWriter("test.css"))
{
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    writer.Write(content);
    writer.Close();
}
```

I tried it in a standard Windows Forms app.

EDIT: The file (Stylesheet1.css) was included as a normal item in the project with a build action of "Embedded Resource".